# Plotting values from JSON object in Recharts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recharts

I have a JSON input and each item in the list has a rating-code value such as this:

```
data = [
    {
        "route": "route1",
        "rating-code": 2200
    },
    {
        "route": "route2",
        "rating-code": 2600
    },
    {
        "route": "route3",
        "rating-code": 2600
    },
    {
        "route": "route4",
        "rating-code": 2200
    },
    {
        "route": "route5",
        "rating-code": 2600
    }
];
```

I'm trying to make a bar chart with Recharts that shoes rating codes on the X-axis and number of routes with that rating code on the Y-axis. I tried using .reduce in order to do this and I am getting the expected output array. I'm am stuck now on what to put in to the Recharts dataKey fields to plot this.

My current function:

```
const newData = data.reduce(function(out, cur) {
        let r = cur['rating-code'];
        out.codes[r] = (out.codes[r] || 0) + 1;
        return out;
        }, 
        {'codes':{}});
```

Which returns something like this:

```
codes: {
    1600: 6,
    1800: 5,
    1900: 1,
    2000: 1, 
    2100: 3,
    2200: 1,
    2300: 1,
    2400: 12, 
    ... }
```

So, I'd like to have the rating codes as my x-axis and the number that corresponds to them as the y axis. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<BarChart data={newData ? }>
    <XAxis dataKey= ??? />
    <YAxis dataKey = ??? />
    <Tooltip />
    <Legend />
    <Bar dataKey = ??? />
</BarChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get this sorted out by changing how I was processing the input routes data.

```
        const newData = data.reduce(
            (acc, el) => {
                acc[el['rating-code']] = (acc[el['rating-code']] || 0) + 1;
                return acc;
            },
            {}
        );

        const codes = Object.entries(newData)
            .map(([key, value]) => {
                return {ratingCode: key, count: value};
            });
```

This returned an array in a format suited to Recharts that looked like:

```
[
   {ratingCode: "1600", count: 6},
   {ratingCode: "1800", count: 5},
   {ratingCode: "1900", count: 1},
   {ratingCode: "2000", count: 1},
   {ratingCode: "2100", count: 3},
   etc.
]
```

And finally was able to plot as intended by:

```
<BarChart data={codes}>
    <XAxis dataKey="ratingCode" />
    <YAxis />
    <Tooltip />
    <Bar dataKey = "count" />
</BarChart>
```